# DELPHI DBgrid Lookup

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, lookup

need help i have 2 tables below

```
      tblA              tblB

      emp_no            emp_no
      cust_no           emp_name
      others.......     cust_no
                        cust_name
```

in delphi i have dbgrid i create 2 lookup with

```
(1) ResultField = emp_name from tblB
    keyfields = emp_no 
    lookupKeyfields = emp_no and 

(2) lookupResultField cust_name from tblB 
    keyfields = emp_no 
    lookupKeyfields = emp_no
```

no problem on this but when i save using applyUpdate only the emp_no is saved to tblA i want to get also the cust_no of lookup and save also to tblA
what is the possible solution on this
thanks

Comment: It jumps right into the eye: have a look at the keyfields and lookupkeyfields of (2)!

Comment: in lookupResultField cust_name id try set keyfields = cust_no but it doesnt give me exact data

Comment: Did you also change the lookupkeyfields?

Comment: @Uwe is correct. This is a simple case of poor copy/paste/edit, where you managed to do the copy/paste but did the edit incorrectly. Fix your `KeyFields` and `LookupKeyFields` in case #2.